# Map reduce in RavenDb over 2 collections with child collection

Tags: c#, mapreduce, ravendb

I have 2 different object types stored in RavenDb, which are a parent/child type relationship, like this in JSON:

```
Account/1
{        
    "Name": "Acc1",
}

Items/1
{
    "Account": "Account/1",
    "Value" : "100",
    "Tags": [
       "tag1",
       "tag2"]
}

Items/2
{
    "Account": "Account/1",
    "Value" : "50",
    "Tags": [
       "tag2"]
}
```

Note that I don't want to store these in the same document, as an account may have thousands of items.

I am trying to write a map/reduce index that will return me something like:

```
{
    "Account": "Acc1",
    "TagInfo": [
        { "TagName" : "tag1",
          "Count" : "1",  //Count of all the "tag1" occurrences for acc1
          "Value" : "100" //Sum of all the Values for acc1 which are tagged 'tag1'
        },
        { "TagName" : "tag2",
          "Count" : "2",  //Two items are tagged "tag2"
          "Value" : "150"
        }]
}
```

i.e. a list of all the distinct tag names along with the number of each and their value.

I think I need to use a multi-map to map the Account and Items collections together, but I can't figure out the reduce part to create the "TagInfo" part of the result.

Is this possible, or am I modelling this all wrong in Raven?

**EDIT:**

The class I want to retrieve from this query would look something like this:

```
public class QueryResult
{
    public string AccountId {get;set;}
    public TagInfo Tags {get;set;} 
}

public class TagInfo
{
    public string TagName {get;set;}
    public int Count {get;set;}
    public int TotalSum {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I figured out a way to do this in an acceptable manner that builds on Daniel's answer, so I'll record it here for any future travellers (probably myself!).

I changed from trying to return one result per account, to one result per account/tag combination, so the index had to change as follows (note the `group by` in the `reduce` is on 2 properties):

```
public class TagsWithCountAndValues : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Item, TagsWithCountAndValues.ReduceResult>
{
    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string AccountId { get; set; }
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public string TagName { get; set; }
        public int TagCount { get; set; }
        public int TagValue { get; set; }
    }

    public TagsWithCountAndValues()
    {
        Map = items => from item in items
                       from tag in item.Tags
                       select new ReduceResult
                       {
                           AccountId = item.AccountId,
                           TagName = tag,
                           TagCount = 1,
                           TagValue = item.Value
                       };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            where result.TagName != null
                            group result by new {result.AccountId, result.TagName}
                            into g
                            select new ReduceResult
                                       {
                                           AccountId = g.Key.AccountId,
                                           TagName = g.Key.TagName,
                                           TagCount = g.Sum(x => x.TagCount),
                                           TagValue = g.Sum(x => x.TagValue),
                                       };

        TransformResults = (database, results) => from result in results
                                                  let account = database.Load<Account>(result.AccountId)
                                                  select new ReduceResult
                                                             {
                                                                 AccountId = result.AccountId,
                                                                 AccountName = account.Name,
                                                                 TagName = result.TagName,
                                                                 TagCount = result.TagCount,
                                                                 TagValue = result.TagValue,
                                                             };
    }
}
```

As before, querying this is just:

```
var results = session
    .Query<TagsWithCountAndValues.ReduceResult, TagsWithCountAndValues>()
    .ToList();
```

The result of this can then be transformed into the object I originally wanted by an in-memory LINQ query.  At this point the number of results that could be returned would be relatively small, so performing this at the client end is easily acceptable.  The LINQ statement is:

```
var hierachicalResult = from result in results
                        group new {result.TagName, result.TagValue} by result.AccountName
                        into g
                        select new
                        {
                            Account = g.Key,
                            TagInfo = g.Select(x => new { x.TagName, x.TagValue, x.TagCount })
                        };
```

Which gives us one object per account, with a child list of `TagInfo` objects - one for each unique tag.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use a Multi Map/Reduce index for that because you want one map on the tags and the other on the account. They don't have a common property, so you can't have a multi maps/reduce here.

However, you can use TransformResult instead. Here's how to do it:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class TagsWithCountAndValues : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Item, TagsWithCountAndValues.ReduceResult>
{
    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string AccountId { get; set; }
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public int TotalSum { get; set; }
    }

    public TagsWithCountAndValues()
    {
        Map = items => from item in items
                        from tag in item.Tags
                        select new
                        {
                            AccountId = item.AccountId,
                            Tag = tag,
                            Count = 1,
                            TotalSum = item.Value
                        };
        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.Tag
                            into g
                            select new
                            {
                                AccountId = g.Select(x => x.AccountId).FirstOrDefault(),
                                Tag = g.Key,
                                Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count),
                                TotalSum = g.Sum(x => x.TotalSum)
                            };
        TransformResults = (database, results) => from result in results
                                                    let account = database.Load<Account>(result.AccountId)
                                                    select new
                                                    {
                                                        AccountId = result.AccountId,
                                                        AccountName = account.Name,
                                                        Tag = result.Tag,
                                                        Count = result.Count,
                                                        TotalSum = result.TotalSum
                                                    };
    }
}
```

Later then, you can query like this:

```
var results = session.Query<TagsWithCountAndValues.ReduceResult, TagsWithCountAndValues>()
    .Where(x => x.AccountId == "accounts/1")                        
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I didn't know about `TransformResults`!  That isn't quite what I wanted though, I was after one result per Account, with a property containing the tag details, see my edit.  Also, the TotalSum above doesn't work, as it sums ALL item values, not just the ones for the account I'm querying (I think the reduce needs to group on account instead of tag?)

Comment: You can't have an index that has a nested class within its result. I don't think you can get what you want in a single index. Instead, I would rather have a few independant indexes and query them all to get all the information you need or change the data model so that it fits that data access pattern better.

Comment: Ok, thanks Daniel. I thought that might be the case, but wasn't too sure. Many thanks for your time.